# Remove Bytes from binary file

Tags: c#

Is There any way to remove Bytes from binary file???

Comment: You should be a bit (or byte) more explicit, I guess ...

Comment: I want to know the best solution to remove specific count of bytes from binary file .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will have to read in everything after the data you want to remove, write it out where the data to remove begins, then truncate the file to the appropriate length.